# C# .Net RegEx: first 3 char must be a number between 1-100 and second 3 char can be any char

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm trying to set RegEx for a console application. And my problem is to define RegEx expression.

I tried;

> ^([1-9][0-9]?|^100){3}[a-zA-Z]{3}$

and

> ^[0-9]{3}[a-zA-Z]{3}$

but I couln't solve it.

> Regex r = new Regex(@"^([1-9][0-9]?|^100){3}[a-zA-Z]{3}$");
>
> if (r.IsMatch(textBox1.Text))    {
>        MessageBox.Show("OK");    } else    {
>         MessageBox.Show("NO");    }

First 3 must be a number between 1-100 and second 3 must be any three chars like "**123ABC**" or "**405006ghd**" or "**7093zyx**".

Comment: How a _one_ character be between 1-100?

Comment: how can "1" be 3 characters ?

Comment: What are the three numbers in range 1-100 in "405006ghd"?

Comment: Try `^(?:100|[1-9][0-9]|0?[1-9]){3}[a-zA-Z]{3}$` https://regex101.com/r/IppdS3/1

Answer (score 1):

In your pattern you can remove the `^` from `^100` because that is already specified at the start of the pattern.

In your example data `405006ghd` does not match because `[1-9][0-9]?` will not allow a leading zero so it can not match the `06`

You could match either 100, or a number 1 - 99 or a number 0-9 with an optional leading zero:

```
^(?:100|[1-9][0-9]|0?[1-9]){3}[a-zA-Z]{3}$
```

In detail

- `^` Start of the string
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `100` Match literally
  - `|` Or
  - `[1-9][0-9]` Match 10 - 99
  - `|` Or
  - `0?[1-9]` Match 1-9 with optional leading 0
- `){3}` Close non capturing group and repeat 3 times
- `[a-zA-Z]{3}` Match a-z A-Z 3 times
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IppdS3/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Your description is not 100% clear.

Your description verbally is: 3 characters that form a number between 1 and 100 and then 3 characters that can be any character.

So the first block would mean 001 to 100 and the second block is any character so it could be "aaa" but also "123" or "..."

In your regular expressions, you used the begin and end of the string (^ and $) so the match must be exact. But then your examples are wrong, because you gave examples with more than 6 characters ...

But let us start some building of regular expressions:
We know, that the first character is either a 0 or a 1 and the following are a character of the range 0-9. So we could start with [01][0-9][0-9].
But that will also include the 000 but we wanted to start with 001.

So we exclude the 000:
(?!000)[01][0-9][0-9]

Edit: I missed the upper limit of 100 here. So I would recommend something like 100|0[1-9][0-9]|00[1-9] which does not need any exclude and is easier to read.

The last 3 characters is now easy: .{3} matches any 3 characters.

So we get at the end:
(?:100|0[1-9][0-9]|00[1-9]).{3}

And you can test the regular expression at https://regex101.com/

Of course: If you want complete matches, then you have to add the ^ and $ again. If you do not want any character, then replace the . with the characters you want to allow there.

Comment: I just see, that I missed the upper limit of 100. I am matching up to 199. Seems that I forgot it when adding the exclude. So we have to use 100|[0-9][0-9] which results in
^(?!000)(100|0[0-9][0-9]).{3}$

Comment: And then it is much easier to read when we avoid the exclusion and give the possible values of the number part which is 100 or 0[1-9][0-9] or 00[1-9]:
^(100|0[1-9][0-9]|00[1-9]).{3}$